# How can i parse specific char/letter from string and add it to a List<string>?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

txtDir is a textBox if I itype inside only hello then in test1 should be only once the word hello
But if i type in the textBox hello1/hello2/hello3
Then in test1 i should see

hello1
hello2
hello3

```
List<string> test1 = new List<string>();
int index = 0;
while(true)
{
    index = txtDir.Text.IndexOf("/");
    string text = txtDir.Text.Substring(0, index);
    test1.Add(text);
    newNodeParsed = new TreeNode(text);
    rootNode.Nodes.Add(newNodeParsed);
}
```

How can I parse and get the text between each '/' and add it to the List ?

Comment: you mean you want to split the string by each "/" and add it to the list separated?

Comment: You should use the `string.Split()` method. You could get it to work with some modifications to the code you already have, but there's no reason to write it out like that when .NET provides the nice helper method for you already.

Comment: `System.String.Split`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: You can use Split as mentioned in above comments like this string text = txtDir.Text.Split('/');

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split the input string into an string array of string fields and convert the array to a list:

```
List<string> test1 = txtDir.Text.Split('/').ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you want to insert the values on the test1 for each word in your textBox splited by '/' character you should do it:

```
List<String> test1 = new List<String>();
test1.AddRange(txtDir.Text.Split('/'));
```